# Populate New Column with Existing Column Based On Criteria

Tags: sql

I am selecting into an existing column C from column A if it has a value greater than zero.  If not then I want to populate it with column B.  It will populate with column A only if column B is zero.  If both column A and B have values it always uses B.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
( 
   CASE
       WHEN column A > 0  THEN column A
       ELSE column B                
   END
)
```

My insert into was correct but my select had the columns reversed which was causing what I thought was an error.  Thanks for all of your help.  What a noob thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database of choice will be extremely useful, as it looks like you are already correct in most RDBMS. Just stick exactly what you have already inside of a select:

```
--Insert based on select
--INSERT INTO [TABLETOINSERT] (ColumnToInsert)
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ColumnA > 0 THEN ColumnA
       ELSE ColumnB
    END AS NewColumn
--Or create a table the select
--INTO [NEWTABLENAME]
FROM [TABLENAME]
```

Or update:

```
UPDATE [TABLENAME]
SET NewColumn = 
    CASE 
       WHEN ColumnA > 0 THEN ColumnA
       ELSE ColumnB
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to update the value permanently and not just change it during select, do:

```
update MyTable
set ColumnC = CASE        
        WHEN ColumnA > 0 THEN ColumnA        
        ELSE ColumnB                
    END
```